# Javascript remove cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `+` button to clone some text fields. I need ability to remove cloned fields.

**Javascript to clone fields:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".add-row" ).click(function(){
      $( "ul.sea-service" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".personal-details1" ).find('input').val("");
   });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<fieldset class="fieldset-borders">
<legend>Sea Service</legend>
<ul id="personal-details3" class="sea-service">     
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="NameOfVessel">Name of Vessel</label>
                <input id="NameOfVessel" type="text" name="NameOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Name of Vessel" />   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="TypeOfVessel">Type of Vessel</label>
                <input id="TypeOfVessel" type="text" name="TypeOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Type of Vessel" />   
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>           
<ul class="personal-details1"></ul>
<button type="button" class="add-row">+</button> 


</fieldset>
```

There is [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c68jo3kr/1/), by clicnking `+` user can clone as many fields as he need, but if added to many clones he should have ability to remove It, for example by clicking `X`.

I've tried to play around, but couldn't achieve It. Have you any ideas?

Comment: why the remove() method does not work ? https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Please show relevant html in the question itself as well as what you have tried. This isn't a code writing service but people will gladly help with code that isn't working as expected. Your demo doesn't even include any control elements to bind events to for a remove

Answer (score 2):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c68jo3kr/3/)**

You could add `remove` button to every cloned row with global class `remove` for example :

```
$( "ul.sea-service" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".personal-details1" )
     .append('<button class="remove">X</button>').find('input').val('');
```

Then attach `click` event remove parent `.sea-service` to the class `.remove` and :

```
$( "body" ).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('.sea-service').remove();
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".add-row" ).click(function(){
    $( "ul.sea-service" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".personal-details1" ).append('<button class="remove">X</button>').find('input').val('');

  });

  $( "body" ).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('.sea-service').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <fieldset class="fieldset-borders">
    <legend>Sea Service</legend>
    <ul id="personal-details3" class="sea-service">  
      <li>
        <ul class="column">   
          <li>
            <label for="NameOfVessel">Name of Vessel</label>
            <input id="NameOfVessel" type="text" name="NameOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Name of Vessel" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="column">   
          <li>
            <label for="TypeOfVessel">Type of Vessel</label>
            <input id="TypeOfVessel" type="text" name="TypeOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Type of Vessel" /> 

          </li>   
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>   
    <ul class="personal-details1"></ul>
    <button type="button" class="add-row">+</button> 


  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all cloned fields:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.add-row').click(function(e) {
    $( "ul.sea-service" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".personal-details1" ).find('input').val("");
  });
  $('.remove-row').click(function(e) {
    $(".personal-details1 *").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <fieldset class="fieldset-borders">
        <legend>Sea Service</legend>
        <ul id="personal-details3" class="sea-service">
            <li>
                <ul class="column">
                    <li>
                        <label for="NameOfVessel">Name of Vessel</label>
                        <input id="NameOfVessel" type="text" name="NameOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Name of Vessel" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="column">
                    <li>
                        <label for="TypeOfVessel">Type of Vessel</label>
                        <input id="TypeOfVessel" type="text" name="TypeOfVessel" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Type of Vessel" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="personal-details1"></ul>
        <button type="button" class="add-row">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="remove-row">-</button>


    </fieldset>
```